# When would they reject a paper in case of violating the double-blind review policy?

Tags: peer-review, conference, paper-submission

a month ago i submitted my paper to double-blind review conference, and their notification date is one month from now.
However, i had presented the work (in an abstract way) 3 months ago in a small symposium as an ongoing work, and i forgot to remove the slides till yesterday. This means if the reviewers had checked my home-page before yesterday, they could have found that i'm the author of this submission.

My question is if my paper is decided to be rejected due to that fact (without any review), would i be notified now or i have to wait until the notification date?

Because if it is already rejected without any review and only due to that issue, it is fair that i could be notified now, so i could send it to another conference around the corner.

Comment: Your concern seems pretty hypothetical. The rules will likely be followed, whatever they are. However, I expect that the reviewers have some responsibility to avoid seeking out the author while reviewing. They may be required to notify the conference chair if they stumble across you and another reviewer would probably be assigned. You could likely withdraw it yourself, but it feels like a panic move.

Comment: @Buffy: I hope so. I do not want to wait 2 months just to know that my paper was rejected at the beginning without any review! And i do not want to do a panic move!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It very much depends on the conference and the reviewers how strict the rules are applied, but in general, it is the responsibility of both the author and the reviewer to not circumvent the double-blind policy. Thus a reviewer should not intentionally invest any effort to find out who the author of the paper is unless it is obvious from the submission itself (a common mistake is referencing own work too obviously).

Double-blind rarely means that you are not allowed to have previous work on a similar topic. There are researchers who publish every year at the same conference with double-blind submission policy. Of course, everybody knows who the author is even if it is not written anywhere in the paper, but just because their work is known in the community. So your case is slightly different because I assume that the name and content of your talk are the same of your submission, so the probability is higher to find your talk if someone searches for the title, but as written above, reviewers should not do that.

Of course, prior official publication of the same paper is usually not allowed, but that does not seem the case for you. In any case, I never came across "desk-rejection" at conferences, so you have to wait until the official notification date.

Comment: I emailed the conference chair and they replied back that my case is not an issue and they have already notified authors of the papers which were problematic regarding double-blind reviewing policy :)